# How to run multiple mix tasks in one command

Tags: elixir

I have multiple `mix` tasks to run in succession. With other build tools, it is possible to run the tasks with a single statement, which saves any startup overhead after the first task. How can this be done with Elixir's `mix` command?

Answer (score 27):

Comma-separate the list of tasks, and add them to `mix do`: `mix do task1, task2, task3`:

```
mix do deps.get, run hello.exs, ecto.migrate
```

For example, the above runs the tasks `deps.get`, `run hello.exs`, and `ecto.migrate` within one invocation of `mix`.

Comment: You don't need the `end` at the end.

Answer (score 9):

You can put an aliases in `mix.exs` and use it.

Eg: `"ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "ecto.seed"]` in this case mix `ecto.setup` will run create, migrate and seed in order